Should I mention dropping out of M2 course in my statement of purpose for PhD application?
I completed my masters in 2020 and I applied for an M2 course in a European nation and was selected. But due to visa issues and some health issues I failed this degree. This degree was in English.
I worked on my health and successfully applied again for an M2 course. I told the person in charge( M2 incharge) that I will apply only if the language of instruction is English (the location is a non-english speaking country in mainland Europe). They told me that all  professors speak English and it won't be a problem.
But on orientation day they refused to give lectures in English. I tried my best to study from different textbooks and translating things, but it became so stressful and owerwhelming that I dropped out of the course and went back to my home country.
Now, I am applying to some PhD programs. I am mentioning that I failed my first M2 in my CV and SOP. Should I also mention that I dropped out of other M2 due to language issues and false promises or it will form  a very negative impression of me that I was consecutively unsucessful in 2 masters? ie I am thinking of writing in my SOP only about 1 st masters and not writing about 2nd masters at all!
I am confused because I failed my 1 st M2 in  April 2023( I joined in September 2022), then I waited in that country till September 2023 to join 2nd M2 and then I had to drop out in December 2023.( If the M2 incharge had told me even once that they can't give lecture in English Or It's better that I learn their language upto a higher level,I would have easily done that, during this time I actually studied this language  but I had no idea of the future and didn't studied for this higher level). There is a gap in my CV. So, I  am confused!

What's an "M2 course"? Do you mean that you applied for another Master's programme?

@AdamPřenosil M2 means 1 year research masters ( year 2 of masters degree).

Why do you think that you need to mention your second M2? Do you have educational gap? It seems that its failure wasn't because of your fault, so, by mentioning it I think you may add unreasonable negative point to your CV. If you think that you must mention it to ensure that it not happen again, you can shortly talk about separately, e.g., just before formally accepting the offer and going to that university.

From my point of view you have two objectives:

Making the strongest possible case for why you are a great fit for their program

Covering your bases in terms of disclosure


While I don't know the plan for your SOP, I would focus more on highlighting the positives (your motivation/interest, your past experience, your skills, past successes) and showing how those set you up to thrive in the program you're applying to. If you need to disclose all past degrees, or if you'd have a CV gap by omitting them, I'd list the truncated degrees in your CV with a brief description for context. Your SOP is your first chance to present yourself to potential supervisors (or program directors); don't waste top billing on something that isn't going to help convince them to admit/hire you.
[That being said- I'm far from the most senior person here, and Europe varies widely. My answer is partially based on the assumption that your applications are a multi-step process, where you're screened based on some brief initial documents and then have some form of interview.]
